# Regular expressions to change order of file names

Tags: regex

I have scanned a set of about 100 printed photographs, giving each one a file name that has a prefix and an autoincremented index, and when I had done already 80 of them, I realized that the order was not the right one. Anyway, I continued, and finished, but now I have 100 files with these names

```
Prefix1_000.jpg
Prefix1_001.jpg
...
Prefix1_099.jpg
```

and it turns out that (let's say) picture "Prefix1_080.jpg" should have been in fact the first one of the set, "Prefix1_081.jpg" the second one, and so on.

I've downloaded PFrank, and it allows me to batch rename files using regular expressions. The problem is that I have little knowledge of them.

I want to rename names on the left to names on the right:

```
Prefix1_000.jpg --> Prefix2_020.jpg
Prefix1_001.jpg --> Prefix2_021.jpg
...
Prefix1_079.jpg --> Prefix2_099.jpg
Prefix1_080.jpg --> Prefix2_000.jpg
Prefix1_081.jpg --> Prefix2_001.jpg
...
Prefix1_099.jpg --> Prefix2_019.jpg
```

Is it possible to do this with regular expressions? If so, which search and replace patterns would you use? I have no problem to change the prefix (to avoid self overlapping).

**Edited**: the discontinuity does not have to be at a number that is a multiple of 10, like 80. It is in fact at an ugly number, like 81.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of least resistance is probably to do it in 10 steps. So rename `Prefix1_(.)0(.)\.jpg` to `Prefix2_\12\2\.jpg`, then rename `Prefix1_(.)1(.)\.jpg` to `Prefix2_\13\2\.jpg`, etc. I wouldn't advise trying to do arithmetic with regular expressions.

To explain the syntax here briefly: each `(.)` means an arbitrary single character (`.`) which should be remembered for later use (`(...)`); the `\.` means exactly a `.` character (as opposed to the "any single character" meaning you saw a moment earlier). Then, in the replacement, `\1` and `\2` mean "the first `(...)` group" and "the second `(...)` group".

As Chris Gessler says, you could also do it with other more general-purpose tools. (If I were faced with the same problem I'd probably do it in Python.) But there's no particular reason not to use the tool you've got.

Comment: That was my main curiosity behind this question. Can I do arithmetic with pieces of the input string, chopped using regular expressions? I've heard so much about them, and they look so powerful, that it's a pitty they don't allow arithmetic in an easy way. Thank you.

Comment: If the break isn't at a multiple of 10 and/or the number of files isn't a multiple of 10, then the approach I described here won't actually work well and you maybe shouldn't have accepted my answer! (Though it was a good answer to the question as originally asked :-).) Regular expressions are powerful, but they aren't a good tool for doing arithmetic with.

Comment: Well, you gave me the answer that it is almost impossible to do it in an arithmetic way. That's also an answer. Frankly, I'm disappointed with reg exps. I think I'll write a renaming tool myself.

Comment: Good luck! You'll probably find yourself implementing a substantial fraction of a real programming language if you want appreciably more flexibility than regexps provide. You should probably do that by embedding an actual programming language: Python or Lua would be reasonable choices.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with PowerShell.  Here the first one, I'll let you handle the rest.  Shouldn't take more than 10 minutes or so.

```
Dir Prefix1_00*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_00","Prefix2_02"  }

Dir Prefix1_01*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_01","Prefix2_03"  }

Dir Prefix1_02*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_02","Prefix2_04"  }

Dir Prefix1_03*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_03","Prefix2_05"  }

Dir Prefix1_04*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_04","Prefix2_06"  }

Dir Prefix1_05*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_05","Prefix2_07"  }

Dir Prefix1_08*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_08","Prefix2_00"  }

Dir Prefix1_09*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_09","Prefix2_01"  }

Dir Prefix1_06*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_06","Prefix2_08"  }

Dir Prefix1_07*.jpg | rename-item -newname {  $_.name  -replace "Prefix1_07","Prefix2_09"  }
```

Took about 10 minutes... enjoy!

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have stated this before. That "80" that I used in my example, is not in fact a nice number like that. Imagine it is "81". So, imagine that the discontinuity is at 81, instead of at 80. It looks like, with your method, I should do 100 different actions, right? In that case, I would just rename them manually.

Comment: Not 100, only 10.  But you could also use an incrementing index for 0-7.